# How to swap values between roles in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have table:

```
ID    ROLE    NAME    TITLE
--    ----    ----    -----
10    DEF     John    Manager
11    UPD     Sam     Engineer
12    DEF     Jill    Lead
13    UPD     Ray     Engneer
```

I need to swap values and get the result:

```
ID    ROLE    NAME    TITLE
--    ----    ----    -----
10    DEF     Sam     Engineer
11    UPD     John    Manager
12    DEF     Ray     Engineer
13    UPD     Jill    Lead
```

How to do this trick with Oracle 11g
Thanks.

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample data, and adjust the result accordingly.

Comment: Do you only need to swap these two names, or are there multiple instances/multiple names you need to swap?

Comment: There is surname and couple of more columns but I think the basics are the same. ID is unique. So ROLE remains but name might change.

Comment: the question is, why do you swap values  in rows 10 and 11 and not in 10 and 12 or 13 or 14 ... ?

Comment: Reasonable question. I edited those tables a bit. So when swapping these values, ROLE matter. Swapping happened based on roles. 12 and 13 swapped as well.

Comment: Well, you *could* swap 10 with 13 and 11 with 12?

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE the_table dst
FROM the_table src
SET dst.name = src.name
        , dst.title = src.title
WHERE dst.id IN (10,11)
AND src.id IN (10,11)
AND src.id <> dst.id
        ;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is valid Oracle syntax?

Comment: No,  I am not.(but it could easiky be changed)